# ssl/tls hanshake:: NIST Special Publication 800-52 Revision 1

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

Can someone explain the contradictions in the BOLD text below from the NIST document.

"The handshake protocol is ***used to optionally exchange X.509*** public key certificates (5) to authenticate the server and the client to each other. In order to comply with these guidelines, ***the server always presents an X.509 public key certificate*** that complies.........."

(4). In these guidelines, “change cipher spec” refers to a protocol, and “ChangeCipherSpec” refers to the message used in that protocol.
(5). The use of ***X.509 public key certificates is fundamental to TLS***. For a comprehensive explanation of X.509 public key certificates see [Adams99] or [Housley01]. In these guidelines, the terms “certificate” and “public key certificate” are used interchangeably.

Comment: This is not a programming question and doesn't fit SO but (IMO) would fit on security.SE. However the answer is trivial: **TLS** handshake has options to use no certs, cert only for server, or certs for both server and client; **800-52** defines a permitted subset of TLS which only uses the latter two options for certs and thus *always* uses a server cert 'that complies with the requirements [of 800-52]' and *sometimes* uses a client cert 'that complies [ditto]'.

Comment: @Dave                                                                                                Thanks Dave. Just two more questions:  1.   what is IMO---where i can post such Qs.    2. If the TLS handshake uses the option of no certs, then how is the authentication taken care by TLS

Comment: (1) IMO = In My Opinion. SE = StackExchange and security.SE = http://security.stackexchange.com . (2) PSK (Pre-Shared Key, except PSK-RSA) uses a pre-shared key; SRP (Secure Remote Password, plain variant) uses a password; Kerberos uses the previously established relationships with the KDC; and DH_anon and ECDH_anon (anonymous) do not authenticate and are frequently prohibited because they don't.